# Feature branch nuget package creating issue

Tags: git, gitversion

INFO [12/05/16 6:55:57:90] Found possible parent branches: origin/develop, origin/release/2.0.0
  WARN [12/05/16 6:55:57:90] Failed to inherit Increment branch configuration, ended up with: origin/develop, origin/release/2.0.0

used below git version configuration for feature/2.0.0  branch

feature:
    regex: features?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false

Nuget created with below naming

Error :'2.1.0-2-0-0-0001' is not a valid version string.